# Have I got this right? (Arrays, Enums. Structs)

Tags: c#, arrays

So, I'm very new to C# (about two weeks) and I've reached a point in my borrowed textbook about Arrays and such.

The examples where pretty clear, but the uses were less so.

If I were to, for example, make a pokemon style game... would I be right to try the following?

Use an Array named "Pokemon" with a range of 150 to handle the initial instance of each pokemon?

Use a struct with variables such as "HP" "Move1" "Move2" "Attack" etc, with values that can be adjusted by the Pokemon array when a Pokemon is needed in battle?

Or should I use an Enum to handle what I thought the Array should do?

This is just an example to help me equate these concepts into something I'd understand better, I'm not looking to rip off pokemon at all.

Comment: Please whoever answers this come up with a better sample :)

Comment: You should call them "Pokeymon" or something to avoid a lawsuit :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For enums, think of them as a way to list different values with words rather than just numbers. For example:

```
enum Element
{
    Normal,
    Fire,
    Water,
    Electric,
    Grass
    //etc.
}
```

Then, a Pokemon class, representing a single Pokemon:

```
class Pokemon
{
    //Properties
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Element ElementalType { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public Pokemon(string name, Element type)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ElementalType = type;
    }
}
```

Thus, you can create Pokemon objects:

```
Pokemon myPokemon = new Pokemon("Pikachu",Element.Electric);
```

The core element of C# (and object oriented programming) is modelizing your data so that it fits in objects which are portable and changeable. Meaning that you can add all sorts of other properties (I went a bit quickly with this), such as HP, Moves, etc.

To create an array:

```
Pokemon[] allMyPokemons = new Pokemon[150];
```

Then you need to set each one:

```
allMyPokemons[0] = myPokemon;
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly seem to be on the right track. Although your array should be able to hold around 500 elements for all those new Pokemon :P

But yes, it is perfectly reasonable to create a struct that contains all of the common information regarding a single Pokemon (name, HP etc). You may even consider taking it a step further and using an array *inside* the struct to store each move. The move could then be another struct containing the move's name and power etc.

It all depends on how detailed you want your application to be, and how much effort you want to put into it. Obviously if this is a learning exercise, you'd want to put in enough effort so that you understand these concepts well.

I'm no C# expert, but if enums in C# are just a group of named integral constants as they are in C++, then they will be of little use to you here.

I think it would be a good idea to start with a simple struct containing the name of a Pokemon, and then create an array of 150 Pokemon. From there, you can add extra detail to your application, like the aforementioned arrays of `Move` structs within the Pokemon struct. Developing iteratively is usually easier than trying to comprehend and solve the entire problem in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# guy, but in general you could keep your pokemon structs in an array, but then you'd have to access them by the array index, which might become cumbersome. I assume that C# arrays can only be indexed by integers.

There are other data structures that might be more useful though. You'll probably find out about those soon enough.  e.g. lists, sets and maps

And yes, you can use structs to group data for something conceptual like a pokemon, or whatever problem you're modeling, in your programs. It might be more useful to use classes however.